# Matplotlib negative axis

Tags: python

I want to fit `y=mx+c` straight line to my data points, but in log form. For this purpose I am using `curve_fit` module. My simple code is

```
def func(x,m,c):
  return (x*m + c)
x=log10(xdata)
y=log10(ydata)
err=log10(error)
coeff, var = curve_fit(func,x,y,sigma=err)
yfit = func(x,coeff[0],coeff[1])
pl.plot(x,y,'r0')
pl.plot(x,yfit,'k-')
pl.show()
```

This plot gives me negative numbers on y axis as my y values are in mV. Is there any way to use original xdata and ydata (in mV) on plots with log fitting?

Answer (score 1):

Plot transformed variables instead.

`plot(10**x, 10**yfit, 'k-')`

and maybe display the plot in log scale

`set_yscale('log')`